# External jar dependcy in java, compile time vs run time

Tags: java

Suppose you have a simple Hello world java program that uses an external user-defined class. When will you need this .jar?
During compile time or during runtime?

It was asked from me in a recent interview and I answered both.

Later I thought that to compile we only need the class definition (i.e. method names, variable names) etc. But can we have that without a .jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During compilation you need either the source file of the class (and compile everything together) or the .class file (compiled file) in your build path. That can be achieved without a .jar file, as long as your external .class file does not have other dependencies as well. 

A jar file can be used for compile time, for runtime, or for both. It depends on what kind of dependency you have. For example, you need it during compilation, and not need it at runtime because you run your application in a managed environment (like an application server) which already has the jar (or a version of it). You needed it directly at runtime if, for example, your code does some dynamic class loading (for example `java.sql.DriverManager` does that when loading the SQL driver class).

And of course, the most common case, when is needed both at compile and run-time.

Answer (score 1):

During runtime you always need the jar.

At compile time, within the devolopping environment (e.g eclipse) the jar file is not neccesarily needed. There are other mechanisms (Build bath settings), available to find the class.
If the project is compiled using a build script, like ant, the external jar is needed to.